# Access database to web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, ms-access

I am trying to turn my access database into a web application.

To do this I'm trying to convert the access database into a SQL Server database. How is this done, or can I manually replicate the database in SQL server form?

Secondly, how would I go about replicating the forms but in ASP.NET C# on separate pages?

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can easily convert an Access database to SQL server using the [Upsizing Wizard](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237980) in Access. It can sometimes be finicky, but usually works. If you need something better then check out the commercial offering [SSW Upsizing PRO! - Access to SQL Server Upsizing Utility](http://www.ssw.com.au/SSW/upsizingpro/default.aspx). Remember, though, that a badly designed database will still be badly designed when converted to SQL Server, so make sure your design is solid and properly normalised (I've seen a lot of "amateur" Access databases and many are very poorly made!). Try and follow SQL Server naming conventions (ie. don't have spaces in table names, don't use tbl prefixes, do be consistent).

As for converting forms to ASP.NET pages that is a huge topic and way beyond the scope of a simple post. You basically need to learn ASP.NET and create data-entry forms that persist the data in the database. Probably your best bet, if you aren't an experienced coder, would be to look at the ASP.NET Dynamic Data site - see the MSDN article [Walkthrough: Creating a New Dynamic Data Web Site Using Scaffolding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488469.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft offers a free tool for migrating different database solutions to SQL Server. Check this link [Free Microsoft SQL Server Database Migration Assistant](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/migration-tool.aspx#Access)